# Sending email with attachment - working fine for non distribution list email contacts but NOT for distribution list email contacts. Why?

Tags: apex

It seems that someone asked [this before](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129092/apex-sending-email-to-distribution-list), but the question was deleted.

I am sending an email with 1..* file attachments to a contact.Id that is specified in a custom setting.

When I specify a contact.Id that has an email of a non-distribution list email address, the email and attachments are sent to the recipient. However, when I change this to an email address which is a distribution list, the email is NOT sent to the contact.

Can someone share some detail on why this is, and how I can get around this? I understand email cannot be sent to more than 100 contacts via apex with the Messaging.MassEmailMessage class method. But I am referencing only 1 contact in the custom setting.

I am also confused with the email log result because I have checked in the email logs, and 'R' is denoted in the 'Mail Event' column (indicating that the email was successfully sent). Despite this, the mail has not been received by the distribution list recipients.

For now, as a workaround, I'm sending the email to a non distribution list email address, and forwarding that onwards to the distribution list via an Outlook rule.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this problem and the my issue was with DL. We can classify DL as internal and external. Internal DL can be used within the organization but external DL can be used from external emails as well.

For Ex:

Internal_DL@example.com is internal DL then it will work if the email is send from example.com domain. If you send email from test@test.com (test.com domain) then it will not work.

So in this I would suggest you to check whether your DL work from external email by sending test email from your personal email account.

In my case that was the issue. Let us know if it fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks very much for this :) I will take a look. Is there any additional information from Salesforce to explain why this has been setup like this? I assume it's to prevent mass emails to customers / non employees.